# Why /Yu and /Yc works on Visual Studio but not with NMake

Tags: visual-studio, makefile, cmake, nmake

I have library.dll who have a stdafx.cpp files. I've create a CMakeLists to make solution for Visual and MakeFiles. When I use the Generator "Visual Studio 12 2013", that compile fine and take this following lines:

```
set_target_properties(core PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/Yustdafx.h")
set_source_files_properties(../core/src/stdafx.cpp PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/Ycstdafx.h")
```

without any problem.

But when I used the NMake MakeFiles generator, it fails and ouput this error :

```
d:\path\to\core\src\filepath.cpp(4) : fatal error C1083: Ca
nnot open precompiled header file: 'stdafx.pch': No such file or directory
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~3.0\VC\bin\cl.exe' : return code
'0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0
\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0
\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Why he finds the precompiled headers with Visual Studio and not with Nmake ?

The only way to compile is to remove the 2 lines I put above for /Yu and /Yc. Is it normal ?

**EDIT :**
Here is my CMakeLists.txt :

```
project(core CXX)
SET(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} /MANIFEST:NO")

# Path of Release
SET(BIN_RELEASE_PATH "../../build/cmake_x86")
SET( CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE "${BIN_RELEASE_PATH}/bin/" )
SET( CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE "${BIN_RELEASE_PATH}/bin/" )
SET( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE "${BIN_RELEASE_PATH}/bin/" )
# Path of Debug
SET(BIN_DEBUG_PATH "../../build/cmake_x86d")
SET( CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG "${BIN_DEBUG_PATH}/bin/" )
SET( CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG "${BIN_DEBUG_PATH}/bin/" )
SET( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG "${BIN_DEBUG_PATH}/bin/" )
# Flags
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /W4 /D_UNICODE /D_USRDLL /DCORE_EXPORTS /DUNICODE")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /Zi /GL /Oi /Gy /O2 /GR- /Gm- /DEBUG")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /GS /analyze- /W4 /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm /Od /fp:precise /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /D_USRDLL /DCORE_EXPORTS /D_WINDLL /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /GR- /Gd /Oy- /MDd /FaDebug /EHsc /nologo /FoDebug ")

# Files of library
add_library(

        core

        SHARED

    ../core/src/file.h
    ...
    ../core/src/file.cpp

)

set_target_properties(core PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/Yustdafx.h")
set_source_files_properties(../core/src/stdafx.cpp PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/Ycstdafx.h")
```

Thanks for help.